# How to combine these formulas in one conditional formatting rule

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

[image: columns of filter duplicate]

I am checking `if column S is empty & Column Q="Consultation"` then I need to set a rule in a cell to make conditional formatting in cell `A1`. So these are my steps:

Step 1: in `X` column: `=if(AND($Q$9:$Q="Consultation",$S$9:$S=""),1,0)`

Step 2: `Y9=SUM(X9:X)`

Step 3: `A1=Y9 >0` , a rule is applied.(conditional formatting custom formula)

The question is how to combine all of these steps in one Array-formula instead of depending on two results successively .

I tried this
`=Arrayformula(sum(if(AND($Q$9:$Q="Consultation",$S$9:$S=""),1,0)>0)` but not working and always return a value of 0

I could remove step 3 and make step 2 : `A=SUM(X9:X)>0`

Comment: *"I am checking if column S is empty & Column Q="Consultation" then i need to set a rule in a cell to make conditional formatting in cell A1"*. Do you want the rule to apply JUST to cell `A1` or the whole column or each cell in column `A`? Please be specific. If you can share the test sheet with expected results.

Comment: To one cell A1 only.. it will be highlighted whenever the the formula is true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To one cell A1 only.. it will be highlighted whenever the the formula is true..

What you need is a **[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)** formula as your conditional rule for cell `A1`

```
=COUNTIFS($Q9:$Q,"=Consultation",S$9:S,"=")>0
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but why "=" !

Comment: *`why "=" !`* Because you ask for column `S` to be blank.

Comment: I mean why it's not as usual ,"" meaning blank

Comment: Because that is how the syntax for `COUNTIFS` works. Please read the reference to it.

Comment: It seems that "" or "="  are interchangeable expressions meaning blank